# how to pass multiple seession to a page in php

Tags: php, session

how can i pass multiple `$_session` to a page with different value
i have a page `action.php` and `index.php`, where the `index.php`submit to `action.php` and the error message is store in a `$_SESSION` but i can only pass one of the `$_session` to the `index.php` here is my index.php

```
 <?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if (isset($_SESSION['userSession'])!="") {
    //header("Location: home.php");
}
error_reporting(0);

$Loginmsg = $_SESSION['LoginMsg'];
$_SESSION['LoginMsg'] = "";
extract($_POST);

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Dashboard</title>

    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Theme style -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css">

    <!--jquery-->
    <script src="plugins/jQuery/jQuery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/summernote.css">
    <script src="dist/js/summernote.js"></script>

</head>

<body class="hold-transition skin-blue sidebar-mini">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <header class="main-header">
            <!-- Logo -->
            <a href="#" class="logo">
                <!-- mini logo for sidebar mini 50x50 pixels -->
                <span class="logo-mini"><b>A</b>LT</span>
                <!-- logo for regular state and mobile devices -->
                <span class="logo-lg"><b>Administrator</b></span>
            </a>
            <!-- Header Navbar: style can be found in header.less -->
            <nav class="navbar navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
                <!-- Sidebar toggle button-->
                <a href="#" class="sidebar-toggle" data-toggle="offcanvas" role="button">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger"></span>
                </a>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <?php  if ($Loginmsg != "") {
                echo '<center><div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">' . $Loginmsg . '</div></center>';

                 } ?>
        <!-- Left side column. contains the logo and sidebar -->
        <?php include'menu.php'; ?>
            <!-- Content Wrapper. Contains page content -->
            <div class="content-wrapper">
                <!-- Content Header (Page header) -->

                <!-- Main content -->
                <section class="content">
                    <?php 
            if(isset($_GET['page']))
            {
             switch($_GET['page'])
            {

                case 'berita': include'form_b.php'; break; 
                case 'users': include'users.php'; break;                    
                case 'media': include'media.php'; break;
                case 'edit': include'edit.php'; break;
                case 'slider': include'slider.php'; break;                  
                case 'list_berita': include'list_berita.php';$order=3; break;

            }   
            }
        ?>
                </section>
            </div>
            <!-- /.content-wrapper -->
            <footer class="main-footer">
                <div class="pull-right hidden-xs">
                    <b>Version</b> 2.3.0
                </div>
                <strong>Copyright &copy; 2015<a href="http://dtc-eng.blogspot.co.id/">Detailed Technology Center</a>.</strong> All rights reserved.
            </footer>
            <div class="control-sidebar-bg"></div>
    </div>
    <!-- ./wrapper -->
    <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.5 -->
    <script src="../bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('.konten').summernote({
                height: 300, // set editor height
                minHeight: null, // set minimum height of editor
                maxHeight: null, // set maximum height of editor
                focus: true, // set focus to editable area after initializing summernote
                toolbar: [
                    ['style', ['style']],
                    ['font', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['height', ['height']],
                    ['table', ['table']],
                    ['insert', ['link', 'hr']],
                    ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']]
                ],

                onPaste: function (e) {
                    var bufferText = ((e.originalEvent || e).clipboardData || window.clipboardData).getData('Text');
                    e.preventDefault();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        document.execCommand('insertText', false, bufferText);
                    }, 10);
                 }



            });


        });
    </script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/datatables/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#example1").DataTable({
                "order": [[<?php echo $order; ?>, "desc"]]
            });
        });
    </script>
    <script>
        $.widget.bridge('uibutton', $.ui.button);
    </script>
    <!-- Sparkline -->
    <script src="plugins/sparkline/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jvectormap -->
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-1.2.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="plugins/jvectormap/jquery-jvectormap-world-mill-en.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery Knob Chart -->
    <script src="plugins/knob/jquery.knob.js"></script>
    <!-- daterangepicker -->
    <!--<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.2/moment.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="plugins/daterangepicker/daterangepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- datepicker -->
    <script src="plugins/datepicker/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- Slimscroll -->
    <script src="plugins/slimScroll/jquery.slimscroll.min.js"></script>
    <!-- FastClick -->
    <script src="plugins/fastclick/fastclick.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE App -->
    <script src="dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE dashboard demo (This is only for demo purposes) -->
    <script src="dist/js/pages/dashboard.js"></script>
    <!-- AdminLTE for demo purposes -->
    <script src="dist/js/demo.js"></script>
    <script>
        $('#tgl_agenda').datepicker({
            format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        })
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

the problem with the above code is that i can only pass one error message via `session` how can i make it as much as i want with different values

Comment: Pass array in session

Comment: Add any pattern like comma separated or using ":"  add in session and then parse for each value where you want

Answer (score 2):

A session can be used just like an array. You don't pass a single variable to a single page. A session makes it possible to save and retrieve data on whatever page you are.

You need to make sure to start your session on top of each page:

```
session_start();
```

if you are handling errors you can create a subarray to contain all of them:

```
$_SESSION['errors'] = array();

 // If there's an error
if ($error) {
    // Add error to array
    $_SESSION['errors'][] = $error;
}

// Check if there are errors
if (is_array($_SESSION['errors']) && count($_SESSION['errors']) != 0) {
    foreach ($_SESSION['errors'] as $error) {
        echo $error."<br />";
    }
}
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //Creating session array to store multiple session values
    $_SESSION['errors'] = array();
    //Value1 
    $sessionvalue1=$_SESSION['userSession'];
    //Value 2
    $_SESSION['errors'][$sessionvalue1]="Value 1";
    $_SESSION['errors']['error2']="Value 2";
?>
```